# How to find names that appear in one sheet but do not appear in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can you find the names from a name list in sheet 1 that do not appear in the name list from sheet 2? The lists do not contain any number. There are only 2 names lists in two different sheets. Some names coincide in both lists but some do not. We want to know which don't. If there is a formula I would highly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the two lists of names are in Column A of Sheet1 and Sheet2.

In cell B1 of Sheet1, enter the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Not found","Found")
```

If the name in cell A1 is found anywhere in Column A of Sheet2, this will return "Found", otherwise it will return "Not found". Copy this formula to the other cells in Column B of Sheet1.

The formula uses the MATCH function to find the row in Sheet2 where the name is found. If the name is not found, MATCH returns #N/A. The formula checks the value returned by MATCH and displays "Not found" or "Found" as appropriate.